# spring-security with spring-boot configuration

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring-boot app that is using Spring-security, configured with Java-config.  Ideally, I will have a customer UserDetailsService so I can add/modify users.  Until then I am failing to configure this correctly.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.1.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.0.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.1.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.0.M1")
compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.0.M1")
```

I have the following Configurations

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll();

        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll();

        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = jdbcUserService();
//        userDetailsService.setDataSource(datasource);
//        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserService() throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(datasource);
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }
}

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationSecurity extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource( dataSource );
    }
}
```

So, I realize that my configurations are wrong but not really sure how to best fix them.  The symptoms are that when I log into my Thymeleaf UI, the session never exires.

I have used various online resources for my spring-security learning & implementation.  Unfortunately, I am still not grasping why this is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be configuring 3 filter chains (3 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters`) but only one of them configures the `HttpSecurity`. That's probably not what you intended to do. Maybe consolidate down to `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and one `GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter` and see where it gets you.

Comment: I consolidated my Security Configuration per your suggestion (I modified my original post).  However, I don't see how to timeout user sessions or to event limit logins one user/session.  I do see "server.session-timeout" in the spring-boot documentation, but nothing for maximum sessions.

Comment: Those are completely new features that you didn't mention before. Suggest you stick to the original topic and open new topics for others.

Comment: Dave, actually the lack of time out was in the original post.  Point taken on the limit session per user - my apologies on the confusion.